# What is the 'ls' command's output layout algorithm (how does it choose no of columns AND entries in each column)?

Tags: ls

I have tried 'ls' command on different directories on my system, the output layout is not consistent between different directories (it is, of course, to make it human-readable-friendly). However, as expected, the output layout is consistent for same directory.

I am just interested in learning how does it choose the number of entries in each column and the number of columns to split the data in. (It is a bit difficult to understand since there are two variables here). (And size of filename is also one of the variables).

Comment: Which `ls` are you using?

Comment: @muru ls (GNU coreutils) 8.25.
On Ubuntu 16.04, (without any extra parameters).

Comment: The [function to calculate number of  columns](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/b1ac4786537bb0e414ba09f3f11430bd9317c96d/src/ls.c#L5077), the functions to print it in columns [sorted vertically](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/b1ac4786537bb0e414ba09f3f11430bd9317c96d/src/ls.c#L4846), [sorted horizontally](https://github.com/coreutils/coreutils/blob/b1ac4786537bb0e414ba09f3f11430bd9317c96d/src/ls.c#L4882).

Comment: Also note that that besides the length of the filenames and the columns of the terminal the usage context influences whether the output is multiple-columns at all; for example, if the output gets piped, it will be single-column anyhow.